# NSPredicate with 64-bit integers?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to use NSPredicate with 64-bit numbers, but for some reason it's failing.  I create a predicate with the following string:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UID == %qu", theUID]
```

And it always fails.  Yet if I loop through my objects and compare `if ( UID == theUID )` I find one that is fine.  I'm really confused as to why this isn't working correctly.

Does the above look correct? My predicates work fine for other integers or even strings.  But this seems to be failing.

Thanks!

**Edit:** So strange... so I create my predicate by doing:

```
NSPredicate *myPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:myString];
```

Now when I print myString, and then print myPredicate (by doing `NSLog(@"%@", blah);`) I get:

> String: UID == 17667815990388404861 Predicate: UID ==
>   9223372036854775807

It's the same string, why are these different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly theUID is not an unsigned value?

A more robust way to build predicates would be to pass in an NSNumber:

```
NSNumber *theUIDNum = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:theUID];
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UID == %@", theUID]
```

This gives you the bonus ability to debug and print out the value of theUINum to make sure it got the transition right.

Comment: Yea I tried that shortly after and it gave me the same result - isn't it strange?  Here is the UID: typedef UInt64 UID;

Comment: What is crazy strange, if I use a UInt64 that is small enough, such as: 0x1FC0000000000051  it works fine, but then a larger integer like: 0xF1303838000016BB  fails...

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: Just a side note, I only just thought about it being unsigned... I should have suggested using [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:] (which I have just corrected in my answer)

Comment: Looks like predicates can't handle 64-bit integers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573134/in-memory-and-in-database-evaluation-of-nspredicate-give-different-results

Answer (score 1):

In your `NSPredicate` you can use something like this

```
let myNSNumber = NSNumber(value: theUID)
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "UID = %i", myNSNumber.int64Value)
```