# In-memory and in-database evaluation of NSPredicate give different results

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

Consider the predicate (`NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:`)

```
 (x | 0) == x
```

evaluated against an object where `x` is a 64-bit integer. This should, of course, always evaluate to true. When evaluated against a database (fetching records where the predicate holds) this works, but when evaluated in memory, this only holds if

```
x <= 0x40000000
```

This actually makes some thwarted sense, since the NSPredicate documentation states that the operands of logical operands are treated as 32-bit signed integers -- but then by the same "logic" the evaluation of the predicate by Core Data (more likely, SQLite) is incorrect.

I can see two solutions:

1. Evaluate the predicate in-memory manually, and hope that Apple will not change the behaviour of NSPredicate in Core Data to match the documentation
2. Somehow work around the issue by not having 64-bit integers

Neither of them is particularly attractive. Any other solutions?

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Core Data database, entities have a 64-bit bitfield, want to fetch all rows with certain bits set; so I compute some bitmask and create a query matching entities with (bitfield | bitmask == bitfield).